# Need aggregation of only the query results

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-aggregation

I need to do an aggregation but only with the limited results I get form the query, but it is not working, it returns other results outside the size limit of the query. Here is the query I am doing

```
{
  "size": 500,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "tags.keyword": "possiblePurchase"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "clientName": "Ci"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "firstSeenDate": {
              "gte": "now-30d"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "term": {
            "tags.keyword": "skipPurchase"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "firstSeenDate": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
   "aggs": {
    "byClient": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "clientName",
        "size": 25
      },
      "aggs": {
        "byTarget": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "targetName",
            "size": 6
          },
          "aggs": {
            "byId": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "id",
                "size": 5
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I need the aggregations to only consider the first 500 results of the query, sorted by the field I am requesting on the query. I am completely lost. Thanks for the help

Comment: can you also post your `mappings` document and some `sample data`?

Answer (score 0):

Scope of the aggregation is the number of hits of your query, the `size` parameter is only used to specify the number of hits to fetch and display.

If you want to restrict the scope of the aggregation on the first n hits of a query, I would suggest the sampler aggregation in combination with your query